# In scrapy, I use XPATH to pick HTML and got many unnecessary "" and ,?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I faced with a problem with parsing http://so.gushiwen.org/view_20788.aspx

[image: Inspector]

This is what I want:

```
"detail_text": ["
    寥落古行宫，宫花寂寞红。白头宫女在，闲坐说玄宗。 
"],
```

but I got this :

```
"detail_text": ["
    ", "
    ", "
    ", "
    ", "
    寥落古行宫，宫花寂寞红。", "白头宫女在，闲坐说玄宗。 
"],
```

and this is my code :

```
#spider
class Tangshi3Spide(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tangshi3"
    allowed_domains = ["gushiwen.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://so.gushiwen.org/view_20788.aspx"
    ]
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//div[@class="main3"]/div[@class="shileft"]')
        domain = 'http://so.gushiwen.org'
        for site in sites:
            item = Tangshi3Item()
            item['detail_title'] = site.xpath('div[@class="son1"]/h1/text()').extract()
            item['detail_dynasty'] = site.xpath(
                u'div[@class="son2"]/p/span[contains(text(),"朝代：")]/parent::p/text()').extract()
            item['detail_translate_note_url'] = site.xpath('div[@id="fanyiShort676"]/p/a/u/parent::a/@href').extract()
            item['detail_appreciation_url'] = site.xpath('div[@id="shangxiShort787"]/p/a/u/parent::a/@href').extract()
            item['detail_background_url'] = site.xpath('div[@id="shangxiShort24492"]/p/a/u/parent::a/@href').extract()
            #question line
            item['detail_text'] = site.xpath('div[@class="son2"]/text()').extract()
            self.items.append(item)
        return self.items



#pipeline
class Tangshi3Pipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = codecs.open('tangshi_detail.json', 'w',     encoding='utf-8')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item))
        self.file.write(line.decode("unicode_escape"))
        return item
```

how can I get the right text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add predicate `[normalize-space()]` to avoid picking up empty text nodes i.e those containing whitespaces only :

```
item['detail_text'] = site.xpath('div[@class="son2"]/text()[normalize-space()]').extract()
```